# Eliminate directory hierarchy while tarring

Tags: linux, tar

```
$ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz files
```

will give me as below:

```
files/
files/1
files/2
files/3
```

--

```
$ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz -C files .
```

will give me as below :

```
./
./1
./2
./3
```

I am not able to figure out the right tar command for an output as below .

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `--transform` option, which takes a sed expression.

```
--transform="s/^\.\///"
```

should have the desired effect.

**Edit** Oops, looks like this will leave a leading './' entry in the tar archive, which is probably not desirable. using @paulsm's answer is probably simpler, but it may miss out on hidden files (files starting with .)

Comment: $ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz -C files --transform="s/^\.//" ... would that be right?

Comment: That would be the correct command line, but it seems to not work properly on cygwin. I'll have to check it once I have a real system

Comment: I tried it on ubuntu .. it says tar:invalid transform expression

Comment: sorry, that needs to be `"s/^\.\///"` - one backslash for the . and one backslash for the forward-slash then the two slashes for the closing sed expression, or you could use `"s@^\./@@"` - using a `@` instead of a `/` for the sed expression

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just:

```
cd files
tar -zcvf /full-path/archive/test.tar.gz *
```

Comment: theres the issue , I would not want to cd into a different directory and then the script looses its context of execution. :(